# Dynamic programming algorithm with an O(n) performance that will give the optimal solution

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming

I am currently learning the dynamic substructure and optimal solution for the coin change-making, and one of the questions given from my teacher is to describe an overall O(n) dynamic programming algorithm that will give the optimal solution and why is it O(n)? Can anyone help me to understand the question? Thank you!

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are interested in?

Comment: Probably this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem